# Azure Kinect Green Screen

Tags: azurekinect

I'm looking for sample code, or getting started to perform a "green screen" with the latest Azure Kinect DK.

- How should I proceed to build and display a color stream with ONLY body area ?
- Is it possible to avoid using body stream ? Because it require a stronger (NVidia computer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just published the new Green screen code sample as part of our GitHub open source repo microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK.
You can find more information at [green screen example](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/tree/develop/examples/green_screen)

If you have any questions about the code, you can open GitHub issue.

Comment: Thanks that great ! You should embed a pre compiled binary in /tool like other too exe

Answer (score 1):

I just received my Azure Kinect device recently and have not yet tried a few things I am interested in so this reply comes not from direct experience, however sample code and the SDK's indicate there may be a viable approach.

You can always try to implement traditional color-recognition algorithms, but if your usage scenario allows it, you can use data from the depth camera to filter only data within a depth range, with the "green screen" being out of range. You can then correlate pixels from the depth camera to the RGB image data to pick out data from the color stream that is within a certain depth range. Also, the background does not have to be a real green screen, but rather just has to be outside of the filtered depth range.

This approach allows you to use the sensor SDK, not requiring the body tracking SDK and its associated GPU requirements.

Comment: Yes that's what we are working on. I was asking on StackOverflow because like many other missing features it was available on Kinect and Kinect v2 SDK